# Set inner property Doesn't update on Outer Object

Tags: c#, .net

Below is my code:

```
void Main()
{
    Test test = new Test();
    test.inner.OperatorId = 5;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(test.inner.OperatorId); //returns 0; Why not 5?
}

public class InnerClass
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public long OperatorId { get; set; }
}
// Define other methods and classes here

public class Test{
    long operatorId;
    string text;
    public InnerClass inner
   {
       get
       {
           return new InnerClass
           {
               Text = text,
               OperatorId = operatorId
           };
       }
       set
       {
           text = value.Text;
           operatorId = value.OperatorId;
       }
   }
}
```

Why doesn't console.out return 5? classes in c# are by reference so affecting the inner object should also affect the reference to it in the outer class? How can I fix this?

Note: There is a reason why test is written this way. It's a simpler way of referring to asp.net controls.

Comment: Might have something to do with `inner`'s get method returning a new InnerClass every time you call it

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with your code.  The second issue relates more to why you don't see the correct value.  However, they're both involved in what's going on, so it's worth mentioning both of them.

**Issue #1:**

This line:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine(test.inner.OperatorId);
```

Calls the getter on `inner` property, which initializes a new instance of it (this happens every single time the getter is called):

```
get
{
    return new InnerClass
    {
        Text = text,
        OperatorId = operatorId
    };
}
```

Are you trying to go for a singleton pattern?  If that's the case, you could check if it's `null` and if it is, then initialize a new instance.  Just be careful with singletons and thread safety.  While if you make a fix suggested in the coverage of the second issue, a new instance will be initialized with the correct value... you would be creating a new instance every single time the getter gets called if you don't fix this issue.

**Issue #2:**

The second issue is something you've brought up in the comments after I posted the first part.  Why isn't the new instance built with the set values? Well, let's take a look at how you're setting the value of `5`:

```
test.inner.OperatorId = 5;
```

Are you setting the `inner` property to a new value for the setter to trigger?  No.  You're setting the `OperatorId` property of the `InnerClass`.  So, the `operatorId` field never gets that value.

Aside form the issues from the first part, if you wanted to keep the same code and get it to work, that line would have to be:

```
test.inner = new InnerClass { OperatorId = 5 };
```

This sets `inner` property to a new instance of the `InnerClass` with the desired `OperatorId` value, which sets the `operatorId` field to the appropriate value.

Comment: but it builds it based on the value of operatorId,  text so it should return that value? No?

Comment: Do you mean it will accept an instance of InnerClass and not long and not string?

Comment: How would you suggest writing this? Every time setting InnerClass with new, with the values I want?

Comment: @Rafi See my edit for a better explanation.  Address the two issues I mentioned and go from there.  It's hard for me to recommend what you should write exactly, since I don't know your requirements and what it is that you're aiming for.  That would be an entirely different subject and above what your question is.  All I can do at this point is tell you why certain things happen, which is what I've done.